# RoR specific user roles inside network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, role

I want to setup a app where each user can have different roles inside a network.

So user A is an "admin" in network X, but also a "client" in network Y. Each role has his own capabilities inside the network. E.g. admin can create posts, client can only destroy his own comments etc.

What is the best table structure to achieve this setup? Should I use Devise + CanCan + ... setup?

Comment: you already know the answe :) use Devise and CanCan

Answer (score 2):

there's a gem called **[rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Usage)** (Role management library with resource scoping) gem, it can also be setup with devise and cancan [link](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial), let's assume that you have model **User**

**installation:**

```
gem "rolify"
bundle
rails g rolify:role Role User
```

you can add role:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

check:

```
user.has_role? :admin
```

if you want to define a role scoped to a resource instance:

```
user = User.find(2)
user.add_role :moderator, Post.first
```

and in your ability.rb:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, Post
  can :write, Post, :id => Post.with_role(:moderator, user).map{ |f| f.id }
end
```

Note that the **with_role** method allows us to restrict the Post instances the user has a role on